# How to immediately release threads waiting on a BlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, blockingqueue

Consider a `BlockingQueue` and a few threads waiting on `poll(long, TimeUnit)` (possibly also on on `take()`).

Now the queue is empty and it is desired to notify the waiting threads that they can stop waiting. The expected behaviour is to have either `null` returned or the declared `InterruptedException` thrown.

`Object.notify()` won't work for `LinkedBlockingQueue` as the threads are waiting on an internal lock.

Any straightforward way?

Comment: Why would you do that? It's up to the BlockingQueue to decide which thread's invocation can resume. Based on the implementation of the BlockingQueue, there is no reliable assumption possible on the queue's state.

Comment: @bfoo, I guess the aim is to terminate the threads gracefully when there is no more work to do.

Answer (score 14):

Javadoc for the BlockingQueue suggests a good way:

> A BlockingQueue does not intrinsically
>   support any kind of "close" or
>   "shutdown" operation to indicate that
>   no more items will be added. The needs
>   and usage of such features tend to be
>   implementation-dependent. *For example,
>   a common tactic is for producers to
>   insert special end-of-stream or poison
>   objects, that are interpreted
>   accordingly when taken by consumers.*

Comment: Good idea: As porters in a big international airport, we used to place an empty white box on the conveyor belt to indicate to the porter on the receiving side that no more bags will come from that flight - that white box is just what you call poison.

Answer (score 5):

The conventional way is to interrupt the threads, but this of course requires that they handle interruptions properly.

This means to catch and handle `InterruptedException`s properly around blocking methods, and to check (and act upon) the `interrupted` flag regularly otherwise.

> There is nothing in the API or language specification that ties interruption to any specific cancellation semantics, but in practice, using interruption for anything but cancellation is fragile and difficult to sustain in larger applications. [...]
>
> Interruption is usually the most sensible way to implement cancellation.

Says [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) in section 7.1.1. An example of handling interruption properly, from same (this is a producer thread, not a consumer, but that difference is negligible in the current context):

```
class PrimeProducer extends Thread {
    private final BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue;

    PrimeProducer(BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime());
        } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
            /*  Allow thread to exit  */
        }
    }
    public void cancel() { interrupt(); }
}
```

An alternative  solution would be to set the timeout parameter of `poll` reasonably low, so that the thread wakes up regularly and can notice interruptions quick enough. Still I believe it is always good practice to handle InterruptedException explicitly according to your specific thread cancellation policy.

Comment: Except it looks very much as if poll() doesn't respond to being interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that there is something wrong with your design. Threads consuming off of a BlockingQueue should not need to be interrupted in such a manner. If they must do something else at a regular interval (such as check the state of a variable) whilst also consuming from the Queue then you should use the poll() method with a timeout set accordingly such that the two actions can be interleaved.