# Thread Producer-Consumer java

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, locks

i have to finish an exercise where i have to go find ".java" files in my folder path using the producer/consumer pattern with at least one producer thread and x consumer threads.

ProducerConsumer-class:
First i tried to stop the consumer when the producer is finished finding files with setting a while loop from true to false which doesn't work. It doesn't work because the threads are still running obviously just not doing anything useful. Now i use a closePool() function (as well).

So the function does work if i dont put up with my locks called locka. And thats basically something i don't understand.

So if i have

```
    loka.lock();
    ende = false;
    loka.unlock();
```

and

```
    while(ende){
        loka.lock();
        System.out.println(xy.getQueue());
        loka.unlock();
    }
```

the closePool() function will never get called. And this is something i don't understand. If i put away the locks in the while loop it does work and the threads do stop.

questions:

1) The ende parameter will be set false anyway so the lock will be finally released.

2) Secondly i did only lock a part of the method and not the object?! As far as i understand it other code in other methods in the same object will still work at the same time. Or is the lock like synchronized and i synchronize the whole object while it is in the lock state?
In my understanding the while loop in the consumer-thread is locked but the producer-thread will still call closePool();

on a extra note: maybe i didn't even design my Producer/Consumer pattern the right way.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class FindJavaVisitorp extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    private BlockingQueue<String> xxx = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);

    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {

        if (file.toString().endsWith(".java")) {

            try {
                xxx.put(file.toString());

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public String getQueue() throws InterruptedException {
        return xxx.take();

    }
}

public class ProducerConsumer {

    private volatile boolean ende = true;
    private Path path;
    private FindJavaVisitorp xy;
    private Lock loka = new ReentrantLock();
    private ExecutorService pepe;

    public ProducerConsumer(Path path, FindJavaVisitorp xy, ExecutorService xyz) {
        this.path = path;
        this.xy = xy;
        pepe = xyz;
    }

    public void produce() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, xy);
        loka.lock();
        ende = false;
        loka.unlock();
        closePool();

    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        while (ende) {
            loka.lock();
            System.out.println(xy.getQueue());
            loka.unlock();

        }
    }

    public void closePool() {
        pepe.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!pepe.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                pepe.shutdownNow();
                if (!pepe.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    System.err.println("Pool couldn't be terminated!");
                }

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            pepe.shutdownNow();

        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path startingDir = Paths.get("/usr/local/");
        FindJavaVisitorp x = new FindJavaVisitorp();
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        final ProducerConsumer pp = new ProducerConsumer(startingDir, x, exec);

        exec.submit(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    pp.produce();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // x.printQueue();

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

            exec.submit(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        pp.consume();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read, because it's not indented correctly. But why do you feel you need locks in the first place? The queue is blocking, so any thread trying to get an element from the queue will wait until there is one. No need for locks. Locking is handled by the queue itself. Since you have a Producer/Consumer assignment, it would be much clearer if you have a Producer class, and a Consumer class, instead of putting everything in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but only if thread goes to check it and not waiting for something else, which in your case is happening. In the while loop threads are waiting for `BlockingQueue` and if queue is empty then then will not get a chance to check the flag variable. Also you don't need locks as you're already using BlockingQueue.
    In your example there's no relation between the two critical sections.

.
Following code will try to guard `loka=false` from any concurrent access.

```
loka.lock();
ende = false;//critical section
loka.unlock();
```

Following code will be free from concurrent access and mutually exclusive from the above critical section.

```
while(ende){
    loka.lock();
    System.out.println(xy.getQueue());//critical section
    loka.unlock();
}
```

As there's nothing common between these two critical sections, mutual exclusion is doing nothing. Since `ende` is volatile guarding it with locks doesn't do anything as [primitive types already have atomic access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

> Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
>     Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile (including long and double variables).

2. Only code inside the guarded block by `lock() and`unlock()` will be locked from concurrent access. Object itself is free to do any concurrent simultaneous (to the locked block) task outside these blocks.

And finally follow proper naming conventions and give your variables meaningful names.

**Main answer** to your problem why your threads are still running is because they're waiting on the `blockingQueue.takeItem()` and they can not be released from it unless queue is filled again, however since Producer is finished there's no possibility of that happening.

**How to avoid this behavior**

There are no methods on BlockingQueue which allow [immediate release of waiting threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306806/how-to-immediately-release-threads-waiting-on-a-blockingqueue)
One thing we can do is make producer put a LAST_ITEM and have consumers check if the item they got is LAST_ITEM and thus they can release themselves.

Following is working code. I have made some modifications to the variable and method names to make them more meaningful.

**JavaFileVisitor**

```
package filevisitor;

import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class JavaFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);

    public static String NO_MORE_ITEMS = "### NO MORE ITEMS ###";

    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        if (file.toString().endsWith(".java")) {
            try {
                blockingQueue.put(file.toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public String getQueueItem() throws InterruptedException {
        String item = blockingQueue.take();
        if(NO_MORE_ITEMS.equals(item)) {
            setNoMoreItems();
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void setNoMoreItems() {
        try {
            blockingQueue.put(NO_MORE_ITEMS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProducerConsumer**

```
package filevisitor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class ProducerConsumer {

    private Path path;
    private JavaFileVisitor fileVisitor;

    public ProducerConsumer(Path path, JavaFileVisitor visitor) {
        this.path = path;
        this.fileVisitor = visitor;
    }

    public void produce() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, fileVisitor);
        fileVisitor.setNoMoreItems();
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            String item = fileVisitor.getQueueItem();
            if(JavaFileVisitor.NO_MORE_ITEMS.equals(item)) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**ProducerConsumerMain**

```
package filevisitor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ProducerConsumerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path startingDir = Paths.get("src/filevisitor");
        JavaFileVisitor fileVisitor = new JavaFileVisitor();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        final ProducerConsumer producerConsumer = new ProducerConsumer(startingDir, fileVisitor);

        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Producer started");
                try {
                    producerConsumer.produce();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Producer finished");
            }
        });

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                    System.out.println(threadName + " Consumer Started");
                    try {
                        producerConsumer.consume();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(threadName + " Consumer finished");
                }
            });
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Executor shutdown, waiting for threads to finish");

        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting main");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Producer started
pool-1-thread-3 Consumer Started
pool-1-thread-2 Consumer Started
Executor shutdown, waiting for threads to finish
pool-1-thread-5 Consumer Started
pool-1-thread-6 Consumer Started
pool-1-thread-4 Consumer Started
src\filevisitor\JavaFileVisitor.java
src\filevisitor\ProducerConsumerMain.java
src\filevisitor\ProducerConsumer.java
pool-1-thread-6 Consumer finished
pool-1-thread-4 Consumer finished
pool-1-thread-3 Consumer finished
pool-1-thread-5 Consumer finished
Producer finished
pool-1-thread-2 Consumer finished
Exiting main
```